# Accessing stored procedures from typed data set

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Hi I am just learning to work with typed DataSets and I can not seem to find a good example on how to work with them with stored procedures.

So far I manage to create the DataSet add the tables and the stored procedures.Here is what I have:

[image]

If for example I would like to use the GetBooks Stored Procedure I would have to pass two parameters.I have tried doing it like this:

```
BooksAndCategoriesDataSet context = new BooksAndCategoriesDataSet();
context.GetBooks(1 , 5)
```

But as you guys already know this does not work.

So how can I use any of the stored procedures in the typed data set in my code?

Comment: Looking at what you have in the designer, I think you are missing something. You don't need to create separate tableadapters for getBooksBy . . .  etc Instead, you can create multiple parameter queries within one tableadapter

Answer (score 1):

First right-click on `DataSet` and do `Add -> Query -> Select stored procedure` (remember that  returned query from stored procedure should match `DataSet`) or you can just drag-and-drop stored procedure from `Server Explorer` in Visual Studio (this one will resolve query returned by stored procedure and create `DataSet` accordingly). That will also create 2 classes: `<DataSetName>TableAdapter` and `<DataSetName>DataTable`.

Next to use it in code you have to use 2 different classes:

```
var ta = new GetBooksTableAdapter();
var dt = new GetBooksDataTable();

ta.Fill(dt, 1, 5); //where 1 is first parameter, 5 is second.
```

To access data returned from DataBase do the following:

```
foreach (GetBooksRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //logic
}
```

I have worked a lot with `DataSets` and I strongly advise not to use them, but I hope this will point you to right direction.